# common js in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to use a commonjs plugin my project and i am using webpack to host and bundle my project.

How can I do that?

My webpack.config file is this:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const lazPerf = require("laz-perf");
console.log(lazPerf);
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "docs"),
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      fs: false,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "docs"),
    hot: true,
  },
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  plugins: [
    // commonjs({ include: /node_modules\/laz-perf/ }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      tree: {
        leafCapacity: 16,
        bufferCapacity: 16,
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

I want to import the "lax-perf" which i have imported at the start of config file.

I imported it there to console it, no other reason.

Any help, please

Comment: `I want to import the "lax-perf" which i have imported at the start of config file.` no you haven't. Unless the letter `x` and `z` suddenly became the same letter while no one was looking.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use `commonjs-loder`.

```
npm install --save-dev commonjs-loader
```

Add commonjs-loader to the module.rules array

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /node_modules\/laz-perf/,
        use: 'commonjs-loader'
      },
    ],
  }
```

Option 2: define `laz-perf` as external
This will tell webpack not to bundle the `laz-perf` modules.

```
externals: {
    'laz-perf': 'laz-perf'
  }
```

Then use the module by:

```js
const lazPerf = require("laz-perf");
```